# How to use react navigation in a const?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I have use const to show components. Now when I use react navigation for a button in const, I see this error: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.navigate')

I have try to add navigation={this.props.navigation} to button for allow nabigation, But not worked.

```
const WomenTab = () => (
    <View>
      <Button onPress={() => {
                        this.props.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.reset({
                          index: 0,
                          actions: [
                            NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Wallet' })
                          ],
                        }))
                      }}>
          <Text>Click</Text>
      </Button>
    <View>
);
```

Library link: http://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is called a [functional component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components), often referred to as a stateless-functional component.

One of the major differences is that SFCs do not automatically receive props, but rather must be passed as arguments. So instead of saying `this.props` you should use this pattern:

```
const WomenTab = (props) => ( // <-- add props as an argument
  <View>
    <Button onPress={() => {
      props.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.reset({
        index: 0,
        actions: [ NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Wallet' }) ],
      }))
    }}>
      <Text>Click</Text>
    </Button>
  <View>
);
```

Since the navigation prop is passed automatically to children of navigators, you don't need to do anything else. If you wanted to pass other props, you would do so as usual:

```
<WomenTab myProp={value} />
```

Another common pattern is to [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the props passed to SFCs like so:

```
const WomenTab = ( {navigation} ) => ( // <-- you can pick the props you want via destructuring
  <View>
    <Button onPress={() => {
      navigation.dispatch(StackActions.reset({
        index: 0,
        actions: [ NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Wallet' }) ],
      }))
    }}>
      <Text>Click</Text>
    </Button>
  <View>
);
```

Hope that helps, best of luck!

Comment: Nice answer. I like your detailed explanation, the destructuring is a nice addition.

Comment: Thank You. This worked fine when I used in normal const. But now I have another const in this library, and not working for this. link: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your `props` to the `const`, something like this

```
const WomenTab = (props) => (
    <View>
      <Button onPress={() => {
                        props.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.reset({
                          index: 0,
                          actions: [
                            NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Wallet' })
                          ],
                        }))
                      }}>
          <Text>Click</Text>
      </Button>
    <View>
);
```

Then when you use your `const` you pass the props that you want.

```
<WomenTab navigation={this.props.navigation} />
```

Comment: Thank You. This worked fine when I used in normal const. But now I have another const in this library, and not working for this. link: http://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view

Answer (score 1):

Basically your props are not being passed from Parent component to child component. Make sure you have defined your WomenTab component in createStackNavigator function. Also pass props in your function component.

```
const WomenTab = (props) => (
<View>
  <Button onPress={() => {
                    this.props.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.reset({
                      index: 0,
                      actions: [
                        NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Wallet' })
                      ],
                    }))
                  }}>
      <Text>Click</Text>
  </Button>
<View>
```

);

Comment: This won't work because you are using `this.props.navigation` there is no `this` you would need to remove `this.` to make it work.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you for mentioning it. I totally forgot to remove the this keyword.